# UITableView, is it possible to have 2 strings in the same cell using left+right justify?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Say I have an array of strings I am displaying the following data in a tableView:

Rank Name Item

The first field is consistant length (4), however the middle field is variable so what I would love to be able to do is somehow split the cell so that Item is right justified. Is there an easy way to do this?

Rank Name Item

So

```
Sarg Bobmarley magic
Capt Huf axe
Peon Yumkru sword
```

Becomes

```
Sarg Bobmarley       magic
Capt Huf               axe
Peon Yumkru          sword
```

Cell method:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    TableViewPracticeAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[appDelegate theArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
}
```

Any thoughts or ideas appricated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a custom cell. There's no NSAttributedString in iOS (Update: iOS6 brings NSAttributedString). Its simple really, here's an example:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *rank = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 20];
        //Mess around with the rects, I am just merely guessing.
        [rank setTag:5];
        [[self contentView] addSubView:rank];
        [rank release];


        UILabel *item = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 5, 220, 20];
        //Important
        [item setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        [item setTag:6];
        [[self contentView] addSubView:item];
        [item release];
    }

    UILabel *rank = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    UILabel *item = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];

    //And now set their texts...

}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

For the others who are going to stumble on this later and try to use the above answer... Try this first: UITableViewCellStyleValue1

This is an iOS pre-defined table cell style with Main label in black (left justified) and secondary text on right in blue (right justified) They can even be different fonts. Eg.:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:30];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    }
    cell.accessoryView = [Some widget you want on the right... or not];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Some Left justified string in whatever font here (BLACK)";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Some right justified string here... in whatever font you want (BLUE)";
    return cell;
}
```

That is pretty much it...   :)

Comment: awesome....iOS has provided so many features for every UI element that its better to search for native ones rather than adding other ones to the native one

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCell` also has a `detailTextLabel` property that, I believe, by default is right justified.  Otherwise, you could create a custom cell either in code or using Interface Builder that would have two labels, one of which has right-justified text.