# Different text alignment to a row in table view

Tags: objective-c

I want to add to my row a different string to the left, and a one to the centre and right .

I have read this: [UITableView, is it possible to have 2 strings in the same cell using left+right justify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906853/uitableview-is-it-possible-to-have-2-strings-in-the-same-cell-using-leftright)

But i did not fully understand how the label is added to the row.

Is there a simple way to just set a string according to alignment ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

//something like :
cell.rightText=
cell.leftText=
```

Comment: What you want to do ? just show 2 string one on left and other on right >

Comment: Yes. and centre also .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom cell (UITableViewCell) with 3 labels:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *leftLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *centerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *rightLabel;

@end
```

and add in your storyboard an UITableViewCell CustomTableViewCell type to your UITableView and connect your labels after in your method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of your tableView delegate change your cell´s identifier to your customtableviewcell like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and now you can use your properties `cell.leftLabel`, `cell.centerLabel` and `cell.rightLabel`

or try this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *leftLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 50, 20];
        [leftLabel setTag:1];
        [leftLabel setText:@"Left"];
        [leftLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [[self contentView] leftLabel];
        [leftLabel release];

        UILabel *centerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 5, 50, 20];
        [centerLabel setTag:2];
        [centerLabel setText:@"Center"];
        [centerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [[self contentView] centerLabel];
        [centerLabel release];

        UILabel *rightLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 5, 50, 20];
        [rightLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        [rightLabel setText:@"Right"];
        [rightLabel setTag:3];
        [[self contentView] rightLabel];
        [rightLabel release];
    }

    UILabel *leftL = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *centerL = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *rightL = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    //Do what you want with them....

}
```

Comment: It seems great, i guess i should create them in story board instead right? but than, if i set 3 labels in my costume cell, on storyboard, will it reproduce them for each row? i will just have to do: labelLeft.text=@"" , when populating the table?

Comment: If you create your custom UITableViewCell in your storyboard, all your cells will have labelLeft, labelCenter and LabelRight so you only need to code `cell.LabelLeft.text = @"Your Text"; cell.LabelCenter.text = @"Your Text"; cell.LabelRight.text = @"Your Text";`inside of your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: i created labels on the cell in storyboard but the don't move with the table when scrolling but stay above it. and i don't have a property for the cell cell.mylabel ...

Comment: I updated mi post with instructions for create your CustomTableviewCell for you have access to your properties cell.leftLabel...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. when i drag the label to the costume cell,  he puts it on the view and not on the cell

Comment: drag your labels in your left panel in storyboard, its more easy. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1s2ivqun63d7ec/Screenshot.png

Comment: Ok its a bug you had to add a new row , thanks a lot .

Comment: by the way, you still can't use the property for a cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this code which contains a UITAbleViewcell type by default given by Apple :

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"] ;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:30];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    }
    cell.accessoryView = [Some widget you want on the right... or not];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"left";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Right";
    return cell;
}
```

If you want to add to center also,

You have to make the label and set their frame and make a custom cell. and set value.

Comment: thanks but i need also the centre this one is not good enough

Comment: See my edit...You have to use the frame of cell. You can make a custom cell and set text here