# UITableView - Row - Multiple alignments

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alignment

I am trying to make a row's contents (in a UITableView) have multiple alignments: left, center and right. I searched Stackoverflow for a solution and found this: [Different text alignment to a row in table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007931/different-text-alignment-to-a-row-in-table-view). The only problem is that the solution is ObjectiveC-based, which I am having trouble translating to a Swift-based solution.

Specifically, I have a UITableView representing an active users list. Loading contents into the table view works fine, but for the sake of readability the contents - divided into three types - need to be visually divided into three different 'sections'. How would I go about doing this? What would the solution above look like in Swift? Thanks in advance.

**Code (for Vive)**

*class declaration*

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

*viewDidLoad()*

```
self.activeIDs.delegate = self
self.activeIDs.dataSource = self
self.activeIDs.rowHeight = 25
self.activeIDs.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
self.activeIDs.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

*cellForRowAtIndexPath*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = activeIDs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellReuseId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ActiveIDTableViewCell

        cell.leftLabel.text = "I go left"
        cell.middleLabel.text = "I go center"
        cell.rightLabel.text = "I go right"

        return cell
}
```

*numberOfRowsInSection*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4 //I randomly chose 4, just for example
}
```

*ActiveIDTableViewCell.swift* - pretty much copied

```
import UIKit

class ActiveIDTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// alloc & init labels
let leftLabel = UILabel()
let middleLabel = UILabel()
let rightLabel = UILabel()

// MARK: Memory Management

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    // never forget to call super in overriden UIKit methods (almost never ;))
    super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // now let's assign these values we've set previously in storyboards
    leftLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    // you created a label, but you need to add this label as a subview of cells view.
    contentView.addSubview(leftLabel)

    middleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    contentView.addSubview(middleLabel)

    rightLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    contentView.addSubview(rightLabel)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") //Xcode points to this line when error is thrown
}

// MARK: Layout

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // here happens all the magic which skips autolayouts. You can ofc set autolayouts from code :)
    let frame = self.contentView.bounds
    // frame was the size of the cell, but we want to set our labels at least 10px from sides of cell - so it looks nicely
    let insetFrame = CGRectInset(frame, 10.0, 10.0)
    // width of each label is width of cell / 3 (you want 3 labels next to each other) minus margins
    let labelWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(insetFrame) - 20.0) / 3.0

    // lets calculate the rects and assign frames to calculated values
    let leftLabelRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(insetFrame), CGRectGetMinY(insetFrame), labelWidth, CGRectGetHeight(insetFrame))
    leftLabel.frame = leftLabelRect

    let middleLabelRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(leftLabelRect), CGRectGetMinY(insetFrame), labelWidth, CGRectGetHeight(insetFrame))
    middleLabel.frame = middleLabelRect

    let rightLabelRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(middleLabelRect), CGRectGetMinY(insetFrame), labelWidth, CGRectGetHeight(insetFrame))
    rightLabel.frame = rightLabelRect
}}
```

I've double checked that things like cell-identifiers and custom classes are correctly set in the storyboard.

Comment: What exactly is troublesome with translating this code to Swift..? Any particular line?

Comment: The objective-c i might get, but it's primarily this: "add in your storyboard an UITableViewCell CustomTableViewCell type to your UITableView and connect your labels after in ... cellForRowAtIndexPath ... change your cell´s identifier to your customtableviewcell" So, I add a cell to my tableview and set its identifier to the swift class's name containing the three labels (pastebin.com/7EgyNGp5), including settings its custom class to that class? Then I simply write this (pastebin.com/CfS47p3q) in the cellForRowAtIndexPath? This outputs unwrapping optional error (nil) where I use cell.leftLabel

Comment: Been working on it and I now use this: http://pastebin.com/5vn1EkGS within my cellForRowAtIndexPath. Only problem is that nothing appears in the tableview - how put these three labels inside the textLabel of the cell?

Comment: You should rather paste the contents of your code into the question instead of 3rd party pages - less troublesome for other devs. You should either work with code or with storyboards. If you deceided to use storyboards, set `textAligment` there. What is more, even if you want to do it in code (what is a bad idea) then you should set `textAligment` in `init` of cell class instead of setting it over and over in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Cell is reusable, and these properties should be set only once, not each time you're dequeuing cells. All this are side notes, not solution to the problem.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for the tips. I'll be sure to edit my existing question in order to provide people with code in the future. :) In your post below I commented regarding which type of solution I'm looking for (storyboard or code) and have decided to go with code - so even more help would definitely be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, small tutorial how to do it, please also look into my comments under your question according to programming best practices:

First file, containing your ViewController:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // here ofc you'll have your array/dictionary of input data
    let titles = ["iOS", "Android", "Windows Phone", "Firefox OS", "Blackberry OS", "Tizen", "Windows Mobile", "Symbian", "Palm OS"]

    // this is to make sure how many rows your table should have
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }

    // here you dequeue tableViewCells, so they're reusable (so your table is fast & responding
    // allocating new resources for new cell is very consuming
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        // fill your data
        cell.rightLabel.text = "I'm right cell"
        cell.middleLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.leftLabel.text = "I'm left cell"

        return cell;
    }
}
```

And second file with cell class:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var middleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightLabel: UILabel!

}
```

And now how to tell you what to do with IB :/. Personally, I prefer code solution, but it was your decision.

1. Copy the code ;)
2. Bring `TableViewController` from objects to your storyboard, in `Identity Inspector` set class to `MyTableViewController`
3. Extend your cell so the height is of desired value (I've set to 50), in `Identity Inspector` set class to `MyTableViewCell`
4. Add 3 labels to your cell
5. Select all 3 labels and add constraints:

   - equal widths
   - equal heights
   - vertical space to top: 10
   - vertical space to bottom: 10
6. Select left label and set:

   - horizontal space to middle label: 10
   - horizontal space to left: 10
7. Select right label and set:

   - horizontal space to middle label: 10
   - horizontal space to right: 10
8. Click on that triangle on bottom right and select `Update Frames`. Everything should be positioned correctly.
9. Select each label, on right panel select `Attributes Inspector`, mark correct alignment in there (left for left label, middle for middle label, right for right label).
10. Connect appropriate label to label in `MyTableViewCell` `IBOutlets`.

Everything should work fine with this solution.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer, it's really appreciated. Though, you say that code solution is better, and I would prefer to use that instead of storyboard - especially since my experience with constraints is not so good!  Anyhow, regarding the code solution, I've looked through your code and made sure my code works just like it. Now, the next step is to set the textAlignment for each label in the MyTableViewCell class's 'init()' method, and then set the contents of the three labels to the contents of the cell.textLabel? If so, what would such an 'init()' method look like?

Comment: @Tice I'll post it as separate answer in a moment, just need to code it, as I'm rather into Obj-C than Swift and can't write in Swift without checking syntax. Also if my answer helped you, please accept it ;) Also, I don't claim code is better - I just consider it "more stable" and prettier in more advanced projects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok another answer (as it's completely different) for code solution instead of using storyboards:

1. Open project settings, delete main interface. You want your project to run from code instead of using Storyboards.
2. Now you must set which controller should run first and set some UIWindow properties.

Change implementation of AppDelegate code below.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // create window and set proper size of it
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) 
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        // assign your controller to be the 'entering' point
        self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyViewController(style:UITableViewStyle.Plain)) 

        // start the app
        return true
    }
}
```

3. You also need to set more details in your controller than via using code.

Copy following code:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UITableViewController {

    // use let to keep ID, as at least in 2 places we need this string, it's easier to maintain it in one place and omit any typos
    let cellReuseId = "cellReuseId"
    let titles = ["iOS", "Android", "Windows Phone", "Firefox OS", "Blackberry OS", "Tizen", "Windows Mobile", "Symbian", "Palm OS"]

    // MARK: Memory Management

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init!(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    // MARK: View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // tell the table which class should be used to dequeue cells with given reuse id (previously you set it in storyboards)
        tableView.registerClass(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseId)
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate && UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.rightLabel.text = "I'm right cell"
        cell.middleLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.leftLabel.text = "I'm left cell"

        return cell
    }
}
```

4. You also have to create your cell class and set all variables in there.

Copy following code:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // alloc & init labels
    let leftLabel = UILabel()
    let middleLabel = UILabel()
    let rightLabel = UILabel()

    // MARK: Memory Management

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        // never forget to call super in overriden UIKit methods (almost never ;))
        super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // now let's assign these values we've set previously in storyboards
        leftLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        // you created a label, but you need to add this label as a subview of cells view.
        contentView.addSubview(leftLabel)

        middleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        contentView.addSubview(middleLabel)

        rightLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        contentView.addSubview(rightLabel)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: Layout

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // here happens all the magic which skips autolayouts. You can ofc set autolayouts from code :)
        let frame = self.contentView.bounds
        // frame was the size of the cell, but we want to set our labels at least 10px from sides of cell - so it looks nicely
        let insetFrame = CGRectInset(frame, 10.0, 10.0)
        // width of each label is width of cell / 3 (you want 3 labels next to each other) minus margins
        let labelWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(insetFrame) - 20.0) / 3.0

        // lets calculate the rects and assign frames to calculated values
        let leftLabelRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(insetFrame), CGRectGetMinY(insetFrame), labelWidth, CGRectGetHeight(insetFrame))
        leftLabel.frame = leftLabelRect

        let middleLabelRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(leftLabelRect), CGRectGetMinY(insetFrame), labelWidth, CGRectGetHeight(insetFrame))
        middleLabel.frame = middleLabelRect

        let rightLabelRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(middleLabelRect), CGRectGetMinY(insetFrame), labelWidth, CGRectGetHeight(insetFrame))
        rightLabel.frame = rightLabelRect
    }
}
```

5. Now you can run the project, everything should run smoothly.

---

Lastly, a small explanation why I personally prefer code:

1. You can't use inheritance in Storyboards. For me it's **not acceptable**. You can't even reuse views (unless you make extra xibs for them). As a result, you can add same subviews and reclick the same autolayouts for cell used in few TableViews -> stupid. If I'm wrong, please correct me, I'd like to know that I'm wrong.
2. It is easier to maintain when using GIT and merging.
3. LayoutSubviews is working properly since at least iOS 3. In the meantime, in storyboards there was a couple of different approaches how to layout things, all working not the best way possible.
4. Most developers don't use real MVC when using Storyboards: even when they do something with view in code, they never create UIView classes.
5. You can't do everything in Storyboards. Drawing using CoreGraphics etc is not possible.
6. Creating complex layouts using Storyboards is troublesome. In the meantime, you can do everything in code much faster.

Comment: I wouldn't know anything about storyboard inheritance, but I still intend to use my storyboard in this project since removing it would cause me to have to redo a lot of things. Nevertheless, I've read through your answer (multiple times) and made the necessary changes to my code. Unfortunately, I'm being thrown the error:"init(coder:) has not been implemented:" in ActiveIDTableViewCell.swift (check my code inside topic question). I've posted (hopefully) all of the relevant code to this matter in my topic question, and hope that you can help me even more to get rid of this error. Thank you :)

Comment: @Tice Well, you still load data from storyboard not from ViewController. You need to remove action from point where this viewcontroller is pushed (is it initial? maybe it's from button click?) and you should call push via code, so you're entering this viewcontroller and skip storyboard in this case. Your code is ok. Also, to prevent this error just add this method (you can base on my init methods).

Comment: I don't understand. My MainViewController is initial - do I need to change anything about this? What init method are you referring to and where?

Comment: @Tice How do you check if your MainViewController is initial - in storyboard, don't you? The matter is that you're using storyboards, so you need to pick storyboard solution or turn this code from AppDelegate (if thats initial one). You can't run viewController solution from storyboard and skip storyboard.

Comment: I understand. I've got the storyboard solution working - except I don't use any constraints at all. Those values that you are referring to (10 everywhere) are they reliant on the rowHeight being 50? Because that would explain why it's not working every time I try setting the constraints with a rowHeight of 32.

Comment: @Tice I think you need to read a tutorial about constraints. You should use them, because otherwise your app won't work properly on different resolutions. Maybe open www.raywenderlich.com, they have some basic tutorials which you can use. These values (10) are just the margins I've set between views, so you wont see text coming just next to screen edge etc.